# How to view two dialog boxes on the linux console, running on the same time?

Tags: linux, bash, shell-scripting, dialog, command-line-interface

I want to view on the Linux console two dialog windows on the same time.

I want a window that views the progress BAR, and the a second tailbox that view the logs are running.

The problem is that the dialog appears always in the center of the console.

What I want is

1. to view the two dialog boxes on the same time on the console,
2. while the progress bar is on the top of the screen,
3. and the the box should present down in the screen.

How to implement this?

How to place the dialog window up or down and not in the central?

```
    dialog --title "RUN TASKS FROM TEXT TABLE" --gauge "Please wait..." 10 70 0
    dialog --tailbox file.log 10 100
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `screen` program.

[image]

**Executing screen manually**

After installing `screen`, execute it by typing `screen` in your console.

Split your screen by pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>a</kbd> then <kbd>S</kbd> (uppercase S, with shift

Enter your first command

After having the fist command executed, press <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>a</kbd> then <kbd>tab</kbd> to switch to the another window.

Press <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>a</kbd> then <kbd>c</kbd>

Enter the second command.

Done.

---

**Using a script**

Create a new directory where you would want to put the script, ie. `~/test/`

Create a `.screenrc` file with the following content:

```
startup_message off
screen dialog --title "RUN TASKS FROM TEXT TABLE" --gauge "Please wait..." 10 70 0
split
focus down
screen dialog --tailbox /var/log/syslog 10 100
```

Then just enter `screen` command to execute the script.

Comment: the problem is that I not want to edit it manual , is shuld be run by bash script , can you please advice how to use the screen command in bash script to do the same as you explain here but from script ?

Comment: I have modified the answer, take a look please

Comment: startup_message off isnt valid in linux the same about focus down

Comment: It is valid, you can take a look here: http://linux.die.net/man/1/screen

The script I have show you works on my Debian box (screenshot attached in the answer).

Comment: HOW IT IS VALID: ( run this on linux and tell me what you see - startup_message off )

Comment: any way its not valid on my linux ( the same on all linux versions )

Comment: From what I see, you are trying to execute `.screenrc` file directly. It is NOT a sh/bash script file, it is a script file for `screen` program. All you need to do is to create `.screenrc` file with the contents I have posted, and then execute `screen` command in the same directory.

Comment: you say here that I need to enrer the screen comand , is it possible to run the screen also from script ?

Comment: Yes, you can create a `script.sh` file with following content: `chdir /your/directory && /usr/bin/screen`.

Comment: I run this screen .screenrc ( but without results )

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17264/discussion-between-maihabunash-and-adam).

Comment: I not understand how you run the two windows , I run the screen command alone and screen .screenrc , both are not works!

Comment: You need to execute `screen` command inside directory where `.screenrc` file is located

Comment: YES I did it and its not works!

Comment: any other ideas?